# Write concurrent log file

Tags: python, logging, apache2, wsgi

I have a WSGI application on apache2, that writes to a log file in the simplest of manners:

```
def log (msg):
    with open (LOGFILE, 'a') as f: f.write (msg)
```

In my sandbox environment it works fine, nevertheless I am a bit concerned about concurrency. If apache2 runs various threads, do I have to fear concurrency problems? Will maybe my log file get scrambled? Will perhaps calls to `log (msg)` fail if another thread is already logging? If this were the case, how would I prevent it?

**EDIT:**
For testing, I run two scripts at the same time from two shells:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

def log ():
    with open ('log', 'a') as f:
        f.write ('message from thread A\n')

while (True): log ()
```

and

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

def log ():
    with open ('log', 'a') as f:
        f.write ('message from thread B\n')

while (True): log ()
```

The log file looks good and no error occurred. Was I lucky or is it safe to write to the same file from two different threads. Filesystem is ext4.

Comment: why not use python logging module? http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: Great. Especially this line: "The logging module is intended to be thread-safe without any special work needing to be done by its clients. It achieves this though using threading locks; there is one lock to serialize access to the module’s shared data, and each handler also creates a lock to serialize access to its underlying I/O." Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the python [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

write file with append mode is ensured atomic in linux OS， so no error occurred